# Add border to bottom of .xib (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to only add a border to the bottom of my .xib view.  I currently have the following code which places a red border on ALL FOUR sides.  I only want the border to be on ONE side, the bottom... How do I set the border to the bottom?

Current Code for class that controls .xib:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    self.contentView.layer.borderWidth  = 5.0f;
    self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.contentView.layer.borderColor  = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
}
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
  bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
  bottomBorder.borderWidth = 1;
  bottomBorder.frame       = CGRectMake(0, self.contentView.frame.size.height - bottomBorder.borderWidth, self.contentView.frame.size.width, bottomBorder.borderWidth);
  [self.contentView.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to make a view that draws a red border at its bottom, then why not just make a red subview and pin it to the bottom?